# Reflect changes Dynamically in javascript gauge in c#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a Web form. Based on its user input, a score is calculated. I want to reflect/represent that score on a gauge. My problem is, the variable which contains the value of score is calculated in code behind but the javascript for the gauge is in the ASPX file. How do I retrieve the value with the script and run it to get my score value reflected in the gauge? Any examples/help would be highly appreciated.

```
<script>
    var g1, g2, g3, g4, total;
    var total= document.getElementById('<%=HiddenField1.ClientID%>').value;
    function gauge() {
        var g1 = new JustGage({
            id: "g1",
            value: total,
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            title: "Big Fella",
            label: "pounds"
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Use a hidden field. Give it a value in the code behind, retrieve it on the client-side & use it in your javascript.

Comment: Can you quote an example? And this event doesnt happen on page load, this javascript runs when a button is clicked.

Comment: ok maybe I've misunderstood - it's quite hard to understand your question. '_Variable which contains the value of score is initialized in codebehind_' - do you need that to perform a calculation in the js?

Comment: Hey, i m sorry. I meant variable to be displayed on gauge is calculated in the codebehind file.

Comment: Is this how it works? user enters value - form is submitted - codebehind does calculation - display new page with gauge.

Comment: you got it fully right.!! Now could you help me with the implementation??

Comment: In that case I think my first comment still applies! Add a hidden field to the gauge page, do the calculation and assign the result to the hidden field, show the page and retrieve it using javascript & use it in the gauge code.

Comment: I am unable to understand. I have added the javascript code. Could u let me know what is wrong in my code??

Comment: Looks ok - are you getting any console errors? can you do a console.log() to check the value of `total`?

Comment: The value comes out to be correct, but i am unable to get it reflected on my gauge control. I am just not able to figure out what the problem is.!!!

Comment: well at least you've solved your original problem and can pas the value to the gauge! What happens if you hard-code a value?

Comment: When I hard-code a value to the gauge, it is reflected upon running the page. But when I pass a value through variable, It doesnt.

Comment: Try `value: parseFloat(total)` or `value: parseInt(total)` depending on whether it's a decimal or an int.